# Is there a way to specify location for downloaded files from Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Currently using this to download a file from Colab

```
files.download('drive/MyDrive/Folder/Draft.pdf')
```

The file is placed in the default Downloads folder on my PC, but can I specify where to write it to? Each time I run this line, it will create copies like Draft(1).pdf but I would like to just overwrite it each time.

The documentation for `files.download` doesn't seem to allow a specified output path, but wondering if there is an alternative method?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the default download location within chrome or whatever browser you’re using, it will match the download location you use to download the file with that function.

If you change it to “Always ask you where to save files” it will ask you where you want to place the file during each download.

If you use Firefox, you can even set the behaviour on a file type level, for example it will only ask you where you want to download zip files but automatically download jpeg files.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `(1)` appended to files can be fixed through a Chrome extension. Additionally, the location can be changed through the Advanced Settings menu in Chrome, as well as in other browsers.
Colab now auto-downloads and overwrites files to the same location.